# Selecting entries with min value through search param

Tags: search, params

Trying to do something quite basic but can't seem to get it right..

I'm searching through a form, and want to select entries where the value 'pax' is equal or more than the searched value.

```
{% set params = {
section:    'ships',
limit:      null
} %}

{# pax #}
{% if craft.request.getParam('pax') %}
  {% set pers = craft.request.getParam('pax') %}
  {% set params = params|merge({'pax' : '>= pers'}) %}
{% endif %}
```

Now, this doesn't seem to work. However, if I'd change the last line to:

```
  {% set params = params|merge({'pax' : '>= 30'}) %}
```

It gives me excellent results. So, what am I doing wrong here?

Much appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently passing a string `'>= pers'` to the array. Change this to:

```
'>= ' ~ pers
```

This "concatenates" the string `'>= '` and the value of your pers variable (converted to a string).

Comment: Awesome! I had tried '>=' pers without the ~, so no succes. This works great, thanks!